# Image url start with https not downloading android

Tags: android, imagedownload

I'm downloading image using url like below,

```
 final String url = article.image.url;
            String parentFolder = ""+article.category_id;
            final String fileName = ""+article.image.id;

            FileManager fileManager = BDevice.getFileManager(mContext);
            final File file = BDevice.getFileManager(mContext).getFile(""+article.category_id, parentFolder, fileName);

            Uri uri = null;
            if (fileManager.isFileExists(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            } else {
                if (url != null) {
                    uri = Uri.parse(url);
                }
            }
            holder.image.setImageURI(uri);
```

But this is working for this url "https://citylanedev.blob.core.windows.net/citylane/2016/10/Pharmacie_Icon.png"
and not working for this url "https://dev.citylaneapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/france-mont-saint-michel-2.jpg". After remove 's' from the second url like "http://dev.citylaneapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/france-mont-saint-michel-2.jpg" its working fine. But i dnt want to remove 's' from the url. I want to download image from the second url. So could you please suggest me any idea to do this?

Comment: It's seem likes proxy issue.

Comment: @MayurRaval Okay thank you.

Answer (score 1):

when I try to open the urls in the browser, [the second one](https://dev.citylaneapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/france-mont-saint-michel-2.jpg)
[image]

gives that warning, mostly it's a server issue that the server claims it's secured but probably it's SSL Certificates aren't installed, you should contact the server admin.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I will check and let you know.